# How can I render one (or multiple) quarto documents from a Python script?

Tags: python, quarto

I'm mostly an R user, and I know that I can render one/multiple documents using the Quarto library with a code like this:

```
library(quarto)

# Rendering a .docx
quarto_render(
  input = "quarto-file.qmd"
  , output_format = "docx"
  , output_file = "report-name.docx"
  , execute_params = list(format = list(docx = list("reference-doc" = "template.docx")))
)
```

I'd like to know if there's a Python library to do this. I saw a Quarto package for Python but I didn't find the functions.